# ajax call goes to error function when i try to redirect from 1st jsp to 2nd jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have created 2 jsp pages.In the 1st jsp screen there is a button called "display".when i click this button the page should redirect to the 2nd jsp screen.

```
I was able to redirect to the 2nd jsp page using window.location() in javascript but the ajax call fails and goes to the error function(). When i click the display button it does not show any dynamic data that is appended to the 2nd jsp.(shows only static content).`

//this is my javascript
var rowsperpage = 10;
var pageno = 1;
var totalpages = 0;
var tablecount=0;

function display()
{
    var flag="two";


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: 'maunualmappingloadutility.jsp?value='+flag+'&Rowsperpage='+rowsperpage+'&Pageno='+pageno,

           success: function(response)
           {               
               var data = $.parseJSON(response);
               var status = data.status;

               if(status && status == "sucess")
               {
                   var tbl="";

                   var textfilemapping=data.textfilemapping;   



                   $.each(textfilemapping, function(key, value)
                   {


                        var id = value.id;
                        var data1 = value.col1;
                        var data2 = value.col2;  
                        var data3 = value.col3;
                        var data4 = value.col4;
                        var data5 = value.col5; 
                        var data6 = value.col6;
                        var data7 = value.col7;
                        var data8 = value.col8; 
                        var data9 = value.col9;


                        tbl += '<tr id="'+id+'">';
                        tbl += '<td >' + id + '</td>';
                        tbl += '<td >' + data1 + '</td>';
                        tbl += '<td >' + data2 + '</td>';
                        tbl += '<td >' + data3 + '</td>';
                        tbl += '<td >' + data4 + '</td>';
                        tbl += '<td >' + data5 + '</td>';
                        tbl += '<td >' + data6 + '</td>';
                        tbl += '<td >' + data7 + '</td>';
                        tbl += '<td >' + data8 + '</td>';
                        tbl += '<td >' + data9 + '</td>';

                        tbl += '</tr>';





                   });
                //  window.location="display.jsp";

                   $("#textfiledata").html(tbl); 
                   pageno = data.PAGENO;
                   totalpages = data.TOTALPAGES;
                   rowsperpage = data.ROWSPERPAGE;

                   enablePrevNext();

                   if(pageno == 1) {
                       $("#btnPrev").addClass("disabled");
                } else if(pageno == totalpages) {
                       $("#btnNext").addClass("disabled");
                }

                   $("#txtPage").val(pageno);
                   $('#lblTotalPages').html(totalpages);
               }
               else 
               {
                     alert("Error in displaying snomed info data");
                     return false;
               } 
           },
           error: function() 
           {
                  alert("Error in displaying snomed info data");
                  return false;
           }
    });

}

function Redirect() {
    window.location="display.jsp";
    display();
 }


function om_nPageRefresh() {
    location.reload();
}

//this is the 1st jsp with the display button in it

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery.css" />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/encstyle.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/textfileloadutility.js"></script>
</head>
<body>            
<div class="blue-nav">
            <div class="blue-pad">
                <div class="dropdown referal-drop pull-left">
                    <a href="#">SNOMED CT Manual Mapping Load Utility</a>                       
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div> 
        </div>  


    <div class="fileter-wrap">

    <form  class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div  style=text-align:center;margin:auto;>
   <input class="btn btn-blue btn-sm btn-xs " id="clickMe" type="button" value="Load" onclick="check();" />

</div>



<div id="Message"></div>



</form>

<div class="clearfix spacer10"></div> 

        <div class="clearfix spacer10"></div> 
</div>

<div class="fileter-wrap">
<label>Task status:</label>
  <div  style=text-align:center;margin:auto;>
 <input  style=text-align:center;  id="click" type="submit" value="Display" onclick="Redirect();" />

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

//this is the 2nd jsp where the data is to be displayed

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery.css" />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/encstyle.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/textfileloadutility.js"></script>
</head>
<body>            
<div class="blue-nav">
            <div class="blue-pad">
                <div class="dropdown referal-drop pull-left">
                    <a href="#">SNOMED CT Manual Mapping Load Utility</a>                       
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div> 
        </div>  


    <div class="fileter-wrap">

<table class="table table-bordered grey-table nomargin" id="">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th >ReferenceId</th>   
                                <th >Id</th>                                
                                <th >Effective time</th>
                                <th >Active</th>
                                <th >Module id</th>
                                <th >Concept id</th>
                                <th >Language code</th>
                                <th >Type id</th>
                                <th >Term</th>
                                <th >CaseSignificanceid</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                         <tbody id="textfiledata">
                    </tbody>
                    </table>



<div class="clearfix spacer10"></div> 
        <div class="col-sm-15 cust-paged">
            <div class="col-sm-5">          
                <button id="btnPrev" class="btn btn-lblue btn-xs" onclick="onClickPrev();">PREVIOUSPAGE</button>
                    <span>Page</span>
                    <input type="text" value="" class="search" id="txtPage" onkeydown="search(this)" >
                    <span>of <label id="lblTotalPages"></label></span>
                <button id="btnNext" class="btn btn-lblue btn-xs" onclick="onClickNext();">NEXTPAGE</button>  
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="clearfix spacer10"></div> 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have created 2 jsp pages.In the 1st jsp screen there is a button called "display".when i click this button the page should redirect to the 2nd jsp screen.

I was able to redirect to the 2nd jsp page using window.location() in javascript but the ajax call fails and goes to the error function(). When i click the display button it does not show any dynamic data that is appended to the 2nd jsp.(shows only static content).`

NOTE:if i create the display button in the 2nd jsp the data is getting displayed properly in the 2nd jsp itself.